# Alternate to Busy-Wait

Tags: java

In my application, Jobs will be submitted dynamically, I need to keep track of submitted job's completion. While I shutdown my application, I want to wait till all the submitted jobs completed. For this I maintain a list of submitted job ids. As soon as process completion notification is raised, I remove the id from the list. When shutdown is called, I am waiting till the list becomes empty.

```
while (!ids.isEmpty());
```

Is there a better way to this busy wait.

Comment: Have a look at `wait` and `notifyAll`

Comment: I'd at least add a `sleep` or `yield` in the while loop at the very least...

Answer (score 1):

If you are implementing the job dispatching and running by hand by creating and starting threads, then you need to use `Object.wait` and `Object.notify` to implement a condition variable.  It is a bit fiddly to get right ...

But a better approach is to use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` service for running your jobs.  That allows you to submit all of the jobs, and then call `shutdown` and `awaitTermination` ... which will wait until all of the queued jobs have completed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you reinventing an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)? In particular, its [`awaitTermination()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method? And yes, `awaitTermination()` does not busy wait ...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do it the other way around:
Each job calls an "exit"-method (in the class that holds the ids) that checks if this is the last process to die. Then there will be no busy-wait loop. Provide each job with an "TerminationHandlerInterface" that have the exit-method.